# Write data on newline in properties file at Runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3.6 version and deployed this project on linux server, 
I have one requirement where i want to write key=value at runtime in properties file, for that 1st a i'hv written below code, but its not working on my side, so please advice me if any thing is there apart from this.

```
def writePropFile(self, propFileName, data):
    try:
        print("propFileName : ",propFileName)
        writeObj = open(propFileName, "a")
        writeObj.write(data+"\n")
    except TypeError as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        print("Closing file obj")
        writeObj.close()
```

In standalone programme its working fine.

Comment: What are you getting as a result in runtime? Is there an error? Are you just not seeing any output? if that's the case, is the function even being called?

Comment: Please describe exactly what your code is doing wrong. Include a full traceback if you're getting an exception, or a description of the output if it's not what you expect.

Comment: No, i'm not getting any error, simply my output comes in one single line only.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error, though I acknowledge you say it works fine in a stand alone function. Can you provide more context around the function? What you have should work fine even if it is a bit verbose compared to `with open(propFileName, 'a') as f: f.write(data + "\n" )`. Perhaps you can print `propFileName` and `data` for a given run and paste the results.

Comment: My code : 

def writePropFile(self, data):
        try:
            writeObj = open("filename.properties", "a")
            writeObj.write(data+"\n")
        except TypeError as error:
            print(error)
Executing function by : 
case 1 - rw.writePropFile("test=test")
case 2 - rw.writePropFile("test1=test1")
case 3 - rw.writePropFile("test3=test3")
Its gives following output:

test=test
test1=test1
test2=test2

but on linux machine its giving following output - 
test=testtest1=test1test2=test2

Comment: Thanks for helping, i got the solution for this just now.
i have added '\r\n' character on the place of '\n'.
Now my functionality working properly.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You have done below changes and its worked fine now.

def writePropFile(self, propFileName, data):
    try:
        print("propFileName : ",propFileName)
        writeObj = open(propFileName, "a")
        writeObj.write("\r\n"+data)
    except TypeError as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        print("Closing file obj")
        writeObj.close()